# Undefined function 'imgradientxy' for input arguments of type 'uint8'

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'd like to call functions like `imgradientxy` or `gray2ind` in matlab, but either one will cause the error of `Undefined function 'imgradientxy' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.`

I'm using R2012a version and added `toolbox` to path.

MATLAB Version: 7.14.0.739 (R2012a)

Mapping Toolbox                                       Version 3.5        (R2012a)

`imgradientxy` and `gray2ind` are native functions of matlab. Why is that happening?

Comment: No. They are NOT native to MATLAB. They are part of the image processing toolbox.

Comment: @woodchips But I've included the image processing toolbox

Comment: check `which imgradientxy` to make sure the functions are visible to matlab

Comment: Seems like your matlab doesn't see the `imgradientxy` ... (if I'm not mistaken it only appeared at the Image Processing Toolbox of Matlab 2012b, and you have 2012a)

Comment: exist imgradientxy

ans =

     0

Comment: Funny. You say only that you have the mapping toolbox. But if you have an old release, they are not there anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `imgradient` and `imgradientxy` functions appear to be new to MATLAB Version R2012b, according to the image processing [release notes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/release-notes.html).

I am, however, using R2011a, and I have access to `gray2ind`. If you still cannot find that one, type `ver` to insure you have properly loaded the image processing toolbox.